# how to refer a tag to fill data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I refer a particular h4 tag which is present in a div, which in turn present in a div, which is also present in a div to fill data from an array?.

Comment: i usually to to find the first overhead id or className and drill down with tags and direct descender selectors from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><div><div><h4 id="head"></h4></div></div></div>  
<script>
document.getElementById("head").innerHTML="some value";
</script>
```

Comment: Explain you answer in details

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```js
function changeText() {
  //uncomment if want to use by tag id
    //document.getElementById('my_tag').innerHTML = "This is a new Heading";
    // if want to use by tag class name
    document.getElementsByClassName('my_tag')[0].innerHTML = "This is a new Heading";
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4 id="my_tag" class="my_tag">This is a Heading</h4>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <button onclick="changeText();">Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```